# Is it possible to specify the upper and lower bounds for nextInt in Mersenne Twister RNG (Java)

Tags: java, apache, kotlin

I have a requirement to generate random numbers, specifically using the Mersenne Twister algorithm, in either Java/Kotlin (for Android). 
I've tried using the Apache commons-math Mersenne Twister implementation which works great to generate random integers. However I need to specify a fairly small range for these, the ints must be between 1 and 100.

It doesn't seem to be possible to specify upper and lower bounds with the Apache implementation. 
Does anyone know of any alternative Mersenne Twister options for Java/Kotlin that accept bounds for the nextInt generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can pass upper boundary of generated int to nextInt method, so it is possible to write simple extension function like that:

```
fun MersenneTwister.nextInt(min: Int, max: Int) = min + nextInt(max - min)
```

Please note that like MT's nextInt result does not include upper boundary, so you might want to add 1 to nextInt's argument if you need this behavior.

Also note that I did not test this function well, so do it yourself before using it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Docs weren't particularly clear about upper bound and your answer is working well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use this piece of code:

```
(returnValueOfMersenneTwister() >>> 1) % range + min;
```

`range` is defined somewhere as constant: `max - min + 1`

Note: I directly modified the source code of MT, but it would work for any `NextInt()` like implementation as well.